# Jest - Testing react with multiple HOC's. Material IU, react-router, mobX in Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, jestjs, enzyme, higher-order-components

I'm trying to write unit tests for a project I have. To simplify the issues, I created a small sample project that shows the issues. You can pull it down from github here: [Github Sample](https://github.com/Savij/react-material-mobx-jest)

Upon Shallow render, the error I get is:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'displayName' of undefined

```
  at createStoreInjector (node_modules/mobx-react/index.js:585:46)
  at node_modules/mobx-react/index.js:698:16
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/Home/Home.tsx:21:76)
  at Object.<anonymous> (src/Home/Home.test.tsx:17:189)
```

The issue I'm having is that I need to unit test components with multiple HOC's. There is one for styles from Material UI, one for react-router and two for mobX injection and observer. You can see the failing test in /src/Home in the file Home.test.tsx.

I can not figure out how to get a jest test to pass on this component. I also have the issue where I add  to the Home Component. It also has the same multiple HOC's so that fails thing as well.

There must be a way to get these types of components tested, but I can't seem to get it to work. Any help would be awesome!

For those that don't want to pull the project, here is a summary of the component under test and the test itself.

**Home.tsx**

```
import withStyles, { WithStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles/withStyles';
import classNames from 'classnames';
import { inject, observer } from 'mobx-react';
import * as React from 'react';
import { RouteComponentProps, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import logo from '../logo.svg';
import { HomeStore } from '../Stores/HomeStore';
import { styles } from './Home.Styles';

interface IProps extends RouteComponentProps<{}> {
    homeStore?: HomeStore;
}

export default withStyles(styles)(
    inject('homeStore')(
        withRouter(
            observer(
                class Home extends React.Component<
                IProps & RouteComponentProps<{}> & WithStyles<typeof styles>,
                {}
                > {
                public render() {
                    const { classes } = this.props;
                    return (
                        <div className={classes.app}>
                            <header className={classes.appHeader}>
                                <img src={logo} className={classNames(classes.appLogo, classes.spin)} alt='logo' />
                                <h1 className={classes.appTitle}>Welcome to React</h1>
                            </header>
                            <p className={classes.appIntro}>
                                To get started, edit <code>src/App.tsx</code> and save to reload.
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    );
                }
            }))));
```

**Home.test.tsx**

```
import { shallow, ShallowWrapper } from 'enzyme';
import * as React from 'react';
import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router';
import { HomeStore } from '../Stores/HomeStore';
import Home from './Home';

jest.mock('react-router-dom');
jest.mock('./Home.styles');

const homeStore = {} as HomeStore;

const props = {
    homeStore: homeStore,
    history: {},
    location: {},
    match: {},
    staticContext: {}
};

describe('Order Tests', () => {
    let homeWrapper: ShallowWrapper;

    beforeEach(() => {
        homeWrapper = shallow(<MemoryRouter><Home {...props} /></MemoryRouter>).first().shallow().first().shallow();
    console.log(homeWrapper.debug());
    });

    it('passes a test', () => {
        expect(true).toBe(true);
    });
});
```